# How to make ArcGIS Online contents sharing level funnel through Organization Admins?

Tags: arcgis-online

Is there any way within ArcGIS Online to notify admins of items as they are shared publicly within an organization?

We are trying to moderate our content more to make sure our users don't share things publicly that they shouldn't.

Is there a way to put such items into a queue so that admins can approve and then share publicly?

I know we can search for all items shared publicly, but it would be nice to have tools to make an admin-approval workflow for publicly shared content.

Any ideas or leads to custom scripts/tools, etc?

Comment: With sharing publicly do you mean the share for all inside the organization or share for all (i.e. the internet)? You can disable the share for all option for all people except admins. See:https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/administer/configure-security.htm under sharing and searching.

Comment: @Carlos, it is sharing publicly for the general public.